# How to convert a uint8 to Eigen:half?

Tags: tensorflow, eigen

I am building a c++ op in tensorflow. It requires to convert a `uint8` value to `Eigen::half` ? However, I did not find a function that does that. But I do notice there is a `half_to_float()`. Is there a similar function `uint8_to_float()` in Eigen library ?

Comment: There seems to be a `float_to_half_rtne` (RTNE: round to nearest, ties to even), so you can go from uint8 to float and from there to half. There is also a `raw_uint16_to_half` to take a uint16 and directly interpret it as a half, but I don't think that's what you want...

Comment: Do you know which header file I should include to use `float_to_half_rtne` ? It seems that it is not working with `third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor`.

Comment: I found them declared in [`Eigen/src/Core/arch/Default/Half.h`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/Half_8h_source.html) (currently v3.3.90) and [`Eigen/src/Core/arch/CUDA/Half.h`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/Half_8h_source.html) (currently v3.3.7), the full name there is `Eigen::half_impl::float_to_half_rtne`, but I'm not sure what versions it is included in.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly cast from `uint8_t` to `Eigen::half`:

```
Eigen::half foo(uint8_t x)
{
    return Eigen::half(x);
}
```

The conversion is likely not very efficient, but it should work: https://godbolt.org/z/Wc_j3X

If you need this a lot, you could think about implementing a small look-up table.